# Regex: Everything up to the fourth space with sed

Tags: regex, sed

I'm developing a small script which gets information from a reflog and attempts to separate out the date and branch name.

The date parsing seems to work well up to the fourth space [here with sample text](http://regexr.com/39vqa) but doesn't work with `sed`.

I've only started guessing at the attempt on the parsing of the release as I want to fix the `sed` issue first.

**Sample input:** `Jul 2 15:16:41 2012 modif-for-release@{Thu Nov 27 14:24:56 2014} branch: Created from refs/remotes/origin/modif-for-release`

**Expected output:** `Jul 2 15:16:41 2012`

I'm on a mac btw.

```
function getRelease(){
git for-each-ref --count=1000 --shell \
--format="%(refname)" 'refs/remotes/origin/*release*'|
while read entry; do
    #GET BRANCHES THEN...#

    git reflog --date="local" --pretty='%cd %gd %gs' "$y" | grep "branch:" > reflog.txt;
    string=$(cat reflog.txt);
    date=$(echo "$string" | sed -e -i '^(.*?)(.\d{4})'); #http://regexr.com/39vqa
    branch=$(echo "$string" | sed -e 's/[^ ]* //');
    echo ${date};
    echo ${branch};    
done
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' file
```

Comment: Yep. in the end this worked `date=$(awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' reflog.txt);`

Answer (score 1):

For this specific case, when the number of spaces is limited, you may want to use `cut`:

```
cut -d' ' -f1-4 file
```

or

```
date=$(cut -d' ' -f1-4 <<< "$string")
```

this print from the field 1 to the fiel4, being them defined by the delimiter space.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
Jul 2 15:16:41 2012 modif-for-release@{Thu Nov 27 14:24:56 2014} branch: Created from refs/remotes/origin/modif-for-release
$ cut -d' ' -f1-4 a
Jul 2 15:16:41 2012
```

---

If you really want to use `sed`, catch the groups and print them back:

```
$ sed -r 's/(([^ ]+ ){3})([^ ]+).*$/\1\3/' a
Jul 2 15:16:41 2012
$ sed -r 's/([^ ]+ [^ ]+ [^ ]+ [^ ]+).*$/\1/' a
Jul 2 15:16:41 2012
```

Answer (score 0):

As for your sample input, you can use `sed` like this as well:

```
sed 's/ modif-for-release.*$//'
```

**Example:**

```
sed 's/ modif-for-release.*$//' <<< "Jul 2 15:16:41 2012 modif-for-release@{Thu Nov 27 14:24:56 2014} branch: Created from refs/remotes/origin/modif-for-release"
Jul 2 15:16:41 2012
```